Has anyone seen the ado.net NumberOfActiveConnections performance counter jump from 1 to extreme number in seconds?
Has anyone seen the ado.net NumberOfActiveConnections performance counter jump from 1 to extreme number in seconds as seen in attached screencast?
Does anyone know what might be causing this?
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AkMQK19uJJanhpNJXN1GxnQekg5YeQ?e=nhREMg

The screencast is asking me to sign in. If you still need an answer to this, could you make it self-contained? Mostly videos are not required for technical questions, but if you feel it is important, a GIF of the video may be preferable.
